# delete images from scoped storage in android 11

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

I want to delete an image file from scoped storage
the images that are showing from the other directories.
I have successfully shown images but now I am unable to delete those images in android 11 the code for deleting images is working fine for android 10 or less.

```
    private void delSysMedia(ImageModel mi) {

       ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
     cr.delete(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(mi.getId())});
      cr.delete(Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(mi.getId())});

    }
```

here is the code that is being used by me in my image service class

Comment: `new String[]{String.valueOf(mi.getId())})` We have no idea whar you are doing. We dont know what id that would be. Also we dont know how you obtained that id. Also we dont know which file in which directory. You should write a better post before someone can help you. What does .delete() return? Do you use it?

Comment: `want to delete an image file from scoped storage` We have no idea where that image would reside. Please mention full path. Also show how you created that image.

Comment: `the images that are showing from the other directories. ` The other directories? Which ones? Your post is pretty unclear.

Comment: Also you should first get the uri for the file. And ten call .delete() for the file uri.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting files on Android 11 onwards you need [MediaStore.createDeleteRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#createDeleteRequest(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.util.Collection%3Candroid.net.Uri%3E)) and pass a list of Uri you want to delete it will show a system default chooser to the user asking to Allow or Deny the deletion of file.

**You can use below code for deleting an Image file.**

```
val uris = arrayListOf<Uri?>()
val uriOfCurrentFile= getImgUri(fileObject.absolutePath)
if (uriOfCurrentFile!= null) {
    uris.add(uriOfCurrentFile)
}

val intentSenderLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
//This function gets Uri of file for deletion
fun getImgUri(
    path: String,
): Uri? {
    try {
        val checkFile = File(path)
        Timber.e("checkDelete- $checkFile")
        if (checkFile.exists()) {
            var id: Long = 0
            val cr: ContentResolver = activity?.contentResolver!!
            val selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf<String>(checkFile.absolutePath)
            val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            val sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
            val cursor = cr.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                "$selection=?", selectionArgs, null
            )

            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                    id = cursor.getString(idIndex).toLong()
                    Timber.e("checkFileID- $id")

                    try {
                        val photoUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            id
                        )
                        return photoUri

                    } catch (securityException: SecurityException) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                            val recoverableSecurityException =
                                securityException as? RecoverableSecurityException
                                    ?: throw securityException
                            recoverableSecurityException.userAction.actionIntent.intentSender
                        } else {
                            throw securityException
                        }
                    }


                }
            }


        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}

//now you have list of Uri you want to delete
if (uris != null && uris.size > 0) {
    var intentSender = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> {
            MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(
                activity!!.contentResolver,
                uris
            ).intentSender
        }
        else -> null
    }
    intentSender?.let { sender ->
        intentSenderLauncher.launch(
            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(sender).build()
        )
    }
}
```

Please note if not an Image File, you will have to replace
**`MediaStore.Images`** with `MediaStore.Video`, `MediaStore.Audio`, `MediaStore.Files` etc.